# What is a correct way of writing data in gzip format?

Tags: go, gzip

My application produces a lot of text data, to reduce disk consumption I want to write data in gzip format

Many goroutines simultaneously call WriteData() function.

But linux gzip complains about corrupted file.

```
zcat ./2021-08-11-00.gz > /dev/null
gzip: ./2021-08-11-00.gz: invalid compressed data--format violated
```

It happend not every time, but about every second-trird writed file.

What is wrong with my code?

My DataWrite package looks like

```
package storage

import (
    "compress/gzip"
    "os"
    "sync"

    "github.com/rs/zerolog/log"
)

type Storage struct {
    handle *os.File
    writer *gzip.Writer

    lock sync.Mutex
}

func (s *Storage) Init(filename string) error {

    file, err := os.OpenFile(filename, os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    s.handle = file
    s.writer = gzip.NewWriter(file)

    return nil
}

func (s *Storage) Shutdown() {

    if err := s.writer.Close(); err != nil {
        log.Warn().Err(err).Msg("Gzip writer close failed")
    }

    if err := s.handle.Close(); err != nil {
        log.Warn().Err(err).Msg("Gzip handle close failed")
    }
}

func (s *Storage) WriteData(data *MyStruct) error {

    s.lock.Lock()
    defer s.lock.Unlock()

    buffer := data.content

    _, err := s.writer.Write([]byte(buffer))

    if err != nil {
        log.Warn().Err(err).Msg("Gzip write failed")
        return err
    }

    if err := s.writer.Flush(); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if err := s.handle.Sync(); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't use `O_APPEND`. I don't know if it causes your problem (I don't see an obvious way that it could, knowing how the gzip writer works) but it isn't right either. It effectively makes a file un-seekable and forces all writes to be at the end.

Comment: Where is `buffer` defined?

Comment: This program is full of compilation errors. @AlexBlack please paste a minimal reproducible program.

Comment: you should be able to write a reproducible example

Comment: I've updated the code snippet,

Comment: `_, err := s.writer.Write([]byte(buffer))` if the underlying buffer writes less than `len(buffer)` you will loose data. AKA you are ignoring `n` you should not. But this has nothing to do with a malformed GZIP, as far as i understand.

Answer (score 1):

You are not synchronizing Shutdown and Write.

```golang
package storage

type Storage struct {
    handle *os.File
    writer *gzip.Writer

    lock sync.Mutex
}

func (s *Storage) Init(filename string) {

    file, err := os.OpenFile(filename, os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    s.handle = file
    s.writer = gzip.NewWriter(file)

}

func (s *Storage) Shutdown() {

    s.lock.Lock() // Here !!
    defer s.lock.Unlock()

    if err := s.writer.Close(); err != nil {
        log.Warn().Err(err).Str("fileName", path).Msg("Gzip writer close failed")
    }

    if err := s.handle.Close(); err != nil {
        log.Warn().Err(err).Str("fileName", path).Msg("Gzip handle close failed")
    }
}

func (s *Storage) WriteData(data *MyStruct) error {

    s.lock.Lock()
    defer s.lock.Unlock()

    cnt, err := s.writer.Write([]byte(buffer))

    if err != nil {
        log.Warn().Err(err).Msg("Gzip write failed")
        return err
    }

    if err := s.writer.Flush(); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if err := s.handle.Sync(); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Here you can see the below working code for gzip compress:

```
package main

import (
    "compress/gzip"
    "log"
    "os"
    "time"
    "sync"
)


type Storage struct {
    handle *os.File
    writer *gzip.Writer
    buffer []byte
    lock sync.Mutex
    Name string
    Comment string
    ModTime time.Time
}

func (s *Storage) Init(filename string) {
    file, err := os.OpenFile(filename, os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    s.handle = file
    s.writer = gzip.NewWriter(file)
    s.Name = "a-new-hope.txt"
    s.Comment = "an epic space opera by George Lucas"
    s.ModTime = time.Date(1977, time.May, 25, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
    s.buffer = []byte("Hello")
}

func (s *Storage) Shutdown() {

    if err := s.writer.Close(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Gzip writer close failed")
    }

    if err := s.handle.Close(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Gzip writer close failed")
    }
}

func (s *Storage) WriteData() error {

    s.lock.Lock()
    defer s.lock.Unlock()

    _, err := s.writer.Write([]byte(s.buffer))

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Gzip write failed")
        return err
    }

    if err := s.writer.Flush(); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if err := s.handle.Sync(); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}

func main() {
    //WriteGzip("test.gzip", "My data")
    s := Storage{};
    s.Init("sss.gzip");
    s.WriteData();
    s.Shutdown();
}
```

**EDIT**
Modified to make it similar than the code in question with little changes. WriteData taking buffer from Storage struct as MyStruct is not in the code.